# iTextSharp not preserving PDF styling after adding js

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, itext

I have an set of PDF files created before using different system.
Those are styled correctly, (using Arial font, bold and normal) - PDF contains Swedish characters, and everything works when I print it.
However, I've been working on an solution to not show the pdf file itself to the user, just start the print dialogue. I have used iTextSharp to include JS code what will automatically print the PDF once started.

Method that adds the JS to the provided file and sends it to the user:

```
protected void StreamPdf(string pdfSource)
    {
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfSource);
        var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream);
        //Add the auto-print javascript
        var writer = pdfStamper.Writer;
        writer.AddJavaScript(GetAutoPrintJs());
        pdfStamper.Close();
        var content = outputStream.ToArray();
        outputStream.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(content);
        Response.End();
        outputStream.Close();
        outputStream.Dispose();
    }
```

Now the thing is - after writing the file back using response, I am loosing the formatting - text that was bold before now is normal, and regional characters are lost (displaying empty squares instead).

Is there any possibility to preserve the formatting?

Comment: Instead of using the `writer.AddJavaScript()` method can you try setting the `pdfStamper.JavaScript` property to your js. http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#addJavaScript(java.lang.String)